# Swift: Programmatically equally space out views over a distance?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift3

Ok, this seems to be a math issue more than anything - I want to spawn a given number of subviews equally distributed (no set gap) over a distance horizontally. 
I want to set a margin on each side and, no matter the number, equally distribute the views across the remaining space. This is what I have:

```
func spawnNodes(num: Int, margin: CGFloat)
    {
        let width = self.bounds.width - 2*margin
        let length = Int(width)/num //20
        var lastPos = margin

        for i in 1...num  {
            let n = Node(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))

            n.center = CGPoint(x: margin+(CGFloat(i*length)/2), y: self.bounds.height*0.2)
            lastPos = n.center.x
            self.addSubview(n)
        }
```

And this equally distributes, but they don't take up all the space:
[image]

What is wrong here? How can I keep a margin on each side and equally distribute the views?

TAKE 2:

```
for i in 1...num  {
            let n = Node(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
            let space = (width - CGFloat(num)*n.bounds.width)/CGFloat(num-1)

            n.center = CGPoint(x: lastPos+space+n.bounds.width+(CGFloat(i*length)/2), y: self.bounds.height*0.2)
            lastPos = n.center.x
            self.addSubview(n)
        }
```

Comment: Don't calculate `length` - calculate the spacing.  You have `n-1` spaces between `n` objects.  `spacing = (width - n*objectWidth)/(n-1)`.  Now increment `lastPos` by `spacing+objectWidth`

Comment: Can you write that out as an example?

Comment: Ok. In the edit above I tried to follow your advice but it did not work. Id appreciate it if you wrote out an answer

Comment: Try

     n.center = CGPoint(x: lastPos+space+n.bounds.width), y: self.bounds.height*0.2)

Comment: Is there a reason you have not tried just adding layout constraints programmatically?

Comment: @GlennRay that did not work. They are all skewed to one side. What should I be setting initial lastPos?

Comment: The initial setting of lastPost should be the way you had it , at "= margin".

Answer (score 2):

Here are my suggestions to make it more simple and clear to implement:

1. Use width of the node in calculations
2. Calculate position of the node left side instead of center
3. Calculate position of each node independently (don't use `lastPos`)
4. In case you have enough space to place all the nodes, calculate `padding`, which is extra space available for a node
5. Otherwise (`padding < 0`), calculate what part of each node can be displayed without overlay. Use the fact the last node is never overlaid

Considering that, implementation might look like:

```
func spawnNodes(num: Int, margin: CGFloat) {
    let width = self.bounds.width - 2 * margin
    let nodeWidth : CGFloat = 50
    var availableWidth = width / CGFloat(num)

    var padding = (availableWidth - nodeWidth) / 2
    if padding < 0 {
        padding = 0
        availableWidth = (width - nodeWidth) / CGFloat(num - 1)
    }

    padding += margin
    let y = self.bounds.height * 0.2
    for i in 0 ..< num  {
        let x = CGFloat(i) * availableWidth + padding
        let n = Node(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: nodeWidth, height: 50))
        self.addSubview(n)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a UIStackView. It makes this trivially easy.

Answer (score 1):

It is just a math problem.   Your first attempt was almost there but has a slight miscalculation of the x coordinate.

It needed to be: margin + (i-1)*length

```
n.center = CGPoint(x: margin+CGFloat((i-1)*length)), y: self.bounds.height*0.2)
```